# Django JSONField dynamic contains and key lookups

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm

I need to filter objects by key-value pair contained in JSONField with list of dicts where key and value are model fields.

This question is related to [Django JSONField list of dicts "contains" filter inside Subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54096211/django-jsonfield-list-of-dicts-contains-filter-inside-subquery)

This one works perfectly:

```
EntityObject.objects.filter(
    data__list_of_dicts__contains=[{'static_key': 'static_value'}]
)
```

But with dynamic values:

```
EntityObject.objects.filter(
    data__list_of_dicts__contains=[{F('field1'): F('field2')}]
)
```

It causes an error:

```
TypeError: keys must be a string
```

And with static key and dynamic value:

```
EntityObject.objects.filter(
    data__list_of_dicts__contains=[{'static_key': F('field2')}]
)
```

Another error:

```
TypeError: F(field2) is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: did you try convert your dynamic key value pairs to string with str()? I'm not sure but I think it worth trying : data__list_of_dicts__contains=[{str(F('field1')): str(F('field2'))}]

Comment: `str(F('field'))` just returns string containing `'F(field)'`. If will represent static value `'F(field)'`, not model field called "field"

Comment: I think you shouldn't use F in this code. because when F is called, nothing returns, it just calls DB and give some instructions about some field, you need to have string values of field1 and field2 to filter EntityObjects. obviously you can't benefit from F here. you need to fetch fields directly.

Comment: It will cause number of DB requests equal to EntityObjects count. I guess dynamic lookup like this is possible at least using RawSQL.